# How meaning of words get richer by adding adjectives?

Tags: semantics, computational-linguistics

I'm looking for resources to study how meaning of words get richer by adding adjectives. I don't know the terms, so I don't know where to look. I want to use them in computational linguistics.

Comment: I believe you might be looking for how adjectives modify words. ""get richer" is rather vague....

Comment: Let me explain I used `rich` rather than `modify`. I'm looking to this aspect of semantic function of adjectives that make the adjective clause (I mean adjective+noun) have more meaning than rather noun itself. I have a background in phenomenology and what I am trying to do is to link what I studied years ago in philosophy to what I am studying at the moment in language models.

Comment: Ok, so you are talking about "adding meaning" to a noun, right? Still, we say in linguistic terms: modify it or describe it.

Comment: I'd start with something like Kennedy 2012 https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/edit/10.4324/9780203206966-36/3-adjectives-chris-kennedy

Comment: and it could be worth looking at pp. 624-628 in Gillon 2018 *Natural Language Semantics: Formation and Valuation* https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/natural-language-semantics